# Trying to insert a picture but when using graphicx package footer moves to the bottom of the page

Tags: graphics, header-footer, fancyhdr

When i put that i am using graphicx, my fancyhdr footer moves to the very bottom of the page? How can i stop it from doing this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Can you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the problem, and edit your question to include it? The example should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, but contain the least amount of code that still demonstrates the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess (a minimal example would help), but including the [`graphics`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphics) or [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package and running `pdflatex` will cause `pdfex.def` to be input. For some reason, that file sets the parameters `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth` to the current values of `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth`. Unless changed, these will have the value for usletter size paper.

It is possible for the `\pdfpageheight` and `\paperheight` to differ. This can happen if `graphicx` is loaded and then later `\paperheight` is changed. What happened in your problem sounds like the text is being sized for A4 paper, but the PDF viewer is showing `usletter` paper (which is shorter than `a4`). If so the solution is to make sure that `\paperheight` is correctly set as early as possible, certainly before loading `graphicx`, and preferably in the `\documentclass` optional argument with a paper size option, for example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```